# Oracle Database performance issue in spring-boot application

Tags: java, database, oracle, spring-boot, oracle10g

We have installed 2 instance of same application in a same datacenter. Both the app is using same oracle DB. But we are observing performance issue in one application. In AppDynamics we can see the response time of one application is much higher that other.

Is it possible to intentionally prioritise/configure the DB such a way. If yes, where should I look into the database.

Any Idea why this is happening? I am totally clueless here.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, yes: if Resource Manager has been enabled it could be the case that different Resource Manager plans have such an impact but experience shows that this feature is seldom used.

In practive this kind of difference can have many cause:-

- different SQL statements run
- data is different
- database statistics differences
- different database configuration
- different hardware
- etc.

The first thing to look at database level is something similar to Statspack report (or AWR if licensing allows) to compare database configuration and activity.

And don't forget that application performance is not only database performance it depends also on application server, network and front-end.